# How do I deserialize the last element of a Serde sequence differently from the rest?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a JSON file (generated by a third-party tool that I cannot change) which contains various arrays that look something like this:

```json
[
    1,
    2,
    {
        "ref": "$path.to.value"
    },
    {
        "arbitaryKey": []
    }
]
```

According to the documentation for this tool, the last element of the array will always be a metadata object containing key-value data, so I would like to deserialize that to a `HashMap` rather than as the `Value` enum that I'm using to represent the rest of the items.

I could use `serde(untagged)` like this:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum ValueOrMetadata {
    Value(Value),
    Metadata(HashMap<String, Vec<ValueOrMetadata>>),
}
```

But this feels inefficient - in the full spec, there are *many* values that are represented as JSON objects, and using `untagged` would mean Serde would have to try (and fail) parsing every other kind before falling back to `Metadata`. This would also potentially give incorrect results if, for example, there was a metadata object with `ref` as a key.

I have also tried using [`SeqAccess::size_hint`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.SeqAccess.html#method.size_hint) in a manual `Deserialize` implementation, but this seems to always return `None` when working with JSON.

How can I tell Serde (either through attributes or a manual `Deserialize` impl) that the last element of this sequence is 'special' in a reliable way?

Comment: In case it's of interest to anyone, the spec I'm trying to parse is here: https://github.com/inkle/ink/blob/master/Documentation/ink_JSON_runtime_format.md

Comment: Serde parses the data structure as its being read. For JSON, it won't know if the current item is the last item until after it's done parsing it - after which, it's too late.

Comment: Because of the streaming nature of serde deserialization this might not be possible with it. I'd probably just deserialize into an intermediate representation like `serde_json::Value` and implement `From<serde_json::Value>` for your type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't actually too difficult to do. You just have to use the same trick that `serde(flatten)` uses to temporarily store the deserialized data before you know what type it should be deserialized as. You can do this using [`serde-value`](https://crates.io/crates/serde-value)'s [`serde_value::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde-value/0.7.0/serde_value/enum.Value.html). You can think of it as being similar to `serde_json::Value`, but not being limited to the constraints of JSON so it can store any serialization value tree. Using this trick we can store the last item separately.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Foo {
    #[serde(with = "different_last_element")]
    items: (Vec<i32>, bool),
}

let foo = Foo {
    items: (vec![1, -2, 23, 9], false),
};

let value = serde_json::to_string(&foo).unwrap();
assert_eq!(&value, r#"{"items":[1,-2,23,9,false]}"#);

let parsed = serde_json::from_str::<Foo>(&value).unwrap();
assert_eq!(parsed, foo);
```

Here is the full module `different_last_element` for the example above.

```rust
mod different_last_element {
    use serde::de::{Error, SeqAccess, Visitor};
    use serde::ser::SerializeSeq;
    use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};
    use serde_value::{Value, ValueDeserializer};
    use std::fmt::{self, Formatter};
    use std::marker::PhantomData;

    pub fn serialize<S, C, T, F>((items, end): &(C, F), serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
        for<'a> &'a C: IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>,
        T: Serialize,
        F: Serialize,
    {
        let mut item_iter = items.into_iter();
        let mut seq = serializer.serialize_seq(item_iter.size_hint().1.map(|x| x + 1))?;
        item_iter.try_for_each(|item| seq.serialize_element(item))?;
        seq.serialize_element(end)?;
        seq.end()
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D, C, T, F>(deserializer: D) -> Result<(C, F), D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
        C: Default + Extend<T> + IntoIterator<Item = T>,
        T: Deserialize<'de>,
        F: Deserialize<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_seq(DifferentLastElementVisitor::<C, T, F> {
            _phantom: PhantomData,
        })
    }

    struct DifferentLastElementVisitor<C, T, F> {
        _phantom: PhantomData<(C, T, F)>,
    }

    impl<'de, C, T, F> Visitor<'de> for DifferentLastElementVisitor<C, T, F>
    where
        C: Default + Extend<T>,
        T: Deserialize<'de>,
        F: Deserialize<'de>,
    {
        type Value = (C, F);

        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            write!(formatter, "sequence with 1 or more items")
        }

        fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
        where
            A: SeqAccess<'de>,
        {
            let mut items = C::default();
            let mut previous_item = None;

            while let Some(item) = seq.next_element::<Value>()? {
                if let Some(previous) = previous_item {
                    let item = T::deserialize(ValueDeserializer::new(previous))?;
                    items.extend(std::iter::once(item));
                }

                previous_item = Some(item);
            }

            match previous_item {
                None => Err(Error::invalid_length(0, &self)),
                Some(last) => {
                    let item = F::deserialize(ValueDeserializer::new(last))?;
                    Ok((items, item))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works well, but ideally we would use something like `serde::__private::de::Content<'de>` instead of `serde_value::Value`. `serde_value` is easy to use, but it only stores owned values. This means we end up copying every string and byte buffer even when we could have taken a reference to the data being deserialized. This is particularly frustrating in the case of `serde_json` since it means it must copy the keys of every map to a newly allocated `String`. This can be avoided by just using `serde::__private::de::Content<'de>` and `serde::__private::de::ContentDeserializer<'de, E>` instead. Keep in mind though, that these are provided for `serde_derive` and are very explicitly "private API, don't use" (An exact quote of the documentation for `ContentDeserializer::new`) so it is recommended that you make your own versions of them in your project.